# tigra calendar and asp.net help, or using javascript in asp.net

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net

```
<input type="text" name="testinput" />
<script language="JavaScript">
new tcal ({
    // form name
    'formname': 'testform',
    // input name
    'controlname': 'testinput'
});

</script>
```

```
<form id="form2" runat="server">
<div style="height: 897px">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Update" Width="122px" />
    <br />
    <br />
    TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTEST<br />
    TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTEST<br />
    TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTEST<br />
    TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTEST<br />
    TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTEST<br />
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
                GridLines="None" Height="147px" Width="694px">
                <RowStyle BackColor="#E3EAEB" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            </asp:GridView>
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="33px" Width="179px">fsafasfa</asp:TextBox>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
</form>
```

I am using tigra calender in an asp.net page, but the datepicker will not show up. The img folder path is the same and i even placed it in my apdata.  I took the code straight from the sample page, and I have even used tigra calender before, but not with asp.net any ideas. Is there another calender tool i should be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used this product before, but it doesn't appear that the script references the correct control or form id.

Answer (score 0):

We use a paid suite, but that code you posted sure looks wrong to me. Is that the whole thing? The script tag has no end tag, you can't start javascript statements with a "new" keyword, the input isn't marked runat=server and neither is the form...

Comment: I posted the whole code if you could check it out it would help me out

Answer (score 0):

I am adding a javascript CalendarExtender to a page,When I click the calendar button to trigger the calendar popup, the calendar displays normally. However, when I scroll down and click the button again, the calendar's position is display on top